# How to build jquery selector for a multifilter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I need to apply filters to n categories in a collection of items. Each categoty has from 2 to 5 subcategories. This is:

```
Category a: a1, a2
Category b: b1, b2, b3
Category c: c1, c2
Category d: d1, d2 d3
Category e: e1, e2, e3, e4, e5
```

My items list have classes like:

```
class="a1 c4 e5"
```

Each item can belong only to one subcategory of each category.

Using jquery I can select items from the same category (union) like this:

```
$(".b1, .b2")
```

And items from diff categories (intersection) like this:

```
$(".a2.b3.d1")
```

Here is my question:

If I select a list of subcategories:

```
mylist = [a1, b1, b3, d2, e2, e4, e5]
```

the final selector would have 6 groups of elements (from mylist the product of same-category-elements: 1 x 2 x 1 x 3 = 6)  separated by comma and 4 elements in each group (mylist refers to 4 categories: a, b, d, and e). This is:

```
myselector = $(.e2.b1.a1.d2, 
               .e4.b3.a1.d2, 
               .e5.b1.a1.d2, 
               .e2.b3.a1.d2, 
               .e4.b1.a1.d2, 
               .e5.b3.a1.d2)
```

I don't know how to write a function that transforms mylist in myselector.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `11` is not a valid class name.

Comment: Thanks @Kolink, you are riht (voted up your coomment). I just corrected it all (Do you know the answer now? Can you vote back up the question? Thanks

Comment: You're looking for a cartesian product. Get a cartesian product of your selected subcategories (grouped into sets by category), join each of the elements in the product array with no space (intersection), and join those intersections with ", ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea as follows:

1. Build an hash table with the key is the category and the value is an array of sub categories which included in the `myList` array.
2. Traverse through the built array recursively and build all available combinations.

Here is the code and demo [on JsBin](http://jsbin.com/imoquc/3/edit/)

```
// The list of all sub categories
myList = [".a1", ".b1", ".b3", ".d2", ".e2", ".e4", ".e5"];

// The function to get the category of a particular subcategory
function getCategory(subCat){
    return subCat.substr(1, 1);
}


// The function to build our selector recursively
function buildSelector(categoryList, categoryIndexArray, categoryIndex)
{
    if (categoryIndex == categoryIndexArray.length - 1)
        return categoryList[categoryIndexArray[categoryIndex]];
    else {
        var results = [];
        var subList = buildSelector(categoryList, categoryIndexArray, categoryIndex + 1);
        $.each(categoryList[categoryIndexArray[categoryIndex]],function(_,e){
            $.each(subList,function(_,e1){
                results.push(e + e1);
            });
        });
        return results;
    }
}

var categories = {}; 
var categoryArray = [];

// build the categories and categoryArray 
$.each(myList,function(_,e){
    var cat = getCategory(e);
    if (categories[cat] === undefined)
    {
        categories[cat] = [];
        categoryArray.push(cat);
    }
    if (categories[cat].indexOf(e) < 0)
        categories[cat].push(e);
});

// build our selector as array of groups
var selectors = buildSelector(categories, categoryArray, 0);

// join all selector groups to get the string form
console.log(selectors.join(","));
```

Comment: Great solution @Trung-Hieu Le!! It seems to work perfectly and it doesn't look like the typical Cartesian product. Thanks